# How to make a 20% tint of a CMYK color in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, print-production

I'm trying to make a tint of a color in illustrator but can't figure out how to do that with CMYK colors. With pantone colors, you're usually able to make a tint by selecting the swatch and clicking the color window, like so:

[image]

However, when I try to do the same with CMYK colors, I just get an option to adjust the color balance, like this:

[image]

So where do I find the tint slider for CMYK colors? I'm working on a project where the client states that the specifically want a 20% tint of #d8c114. I don't want to use the color balance option, because I want to have essentially the same swatch, only lighter. It seems like it should be possible since I'm able to do tinted CMYK colors in indesign.

Answer (score 2):

- Drag the CMYK color to the **Swatches** panel.
- Double-click that swatch... 
  (Or highlight the swatch and choose `Swatch Options...` from the Swatch Panel menu)
- Tick the `Global` option and then `OK`

[image]

The color will then have a single slider similar to spot colors, but it is still a CMYk color

[image]

More info regarding Global Colors can be found in the [Help Files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/global-color-swatch.html).

Comment: Is there any way to save the custom tint as a separate swatch?

Comment: @E.B. yes.. just like with spot colors, reduce the tint slider and drag the color to the Swatch Panel = new swatch or that tint. Usage of Global colors in Illustrator is basically the same as usage of spot colors. The difference is in the color separations.